# Testing download links with Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm attempting to build an automated test with Nightwatch.js in order to verify that software download links are working correctly. I don't want to download the files, as they are quite large, I just want to verify that the corresponding link is returning a 200 HTTP response to make sure the links are pointing to the proper place.

Any idea for ways to test links to downloadable files with Nightwatch.js?

Here's what I currently have:

```
/**
 * Test Software Downloads
 * 
 * Verify that software downloads are working 
 */

module.exports = {
    "Download redirect links": function (browser) {

        // download links
        var downloadLinks = {
            "software-download-latest-mac": "http://downloads.company.com/mac/latest/",
            "software-download-latest-linux": "http://downloads.company.com/linux/latest/",
            "software-download-latest-win32": "http://downloads.company.com/windows/32/latest/",
            "software-download-latest-win64": "http://downloads.company.com/windows/64/latest/"
        };

        // loop through download links
        for (var key in downloadLinks) {
            if (downloadLinks.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                // test each link's status
                browser
                    .url(downloadLinks[key]);
            }
        }

        // end testing
        browser.end();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use the node `http` module and make a "HEAD" request
2. For example: assert the filesize

**test.js**

```
var http = require("http");

module.exports = {
  "Is file avaliable" : function (client) {
    var request = http.request({
        host: "www.google.com",
        port: 80,
        path: "/images/srpr/logo11w.png",
        method: "HEAD"
    }, function (response) {
      client
        .assert.equal(response.headers["content-length"], 14022, 'Same file size');
      client.end();
    }).on("error", function (err) {
      console.log(err);
      client.end();
    }).end();
  }
};
```

**References**

- [Check if file exists on FTPS site using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951649/check-if-file-exists-on-ftps-site-using-curl)
- [Protractor e2e test case for downloading pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935696/protractor-e2e-test-case-for-downloading-pdf-file)
- [Stop downloading the data in nodejs request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194017/stop-downloading-the-data-in-nodejs-request)

Comment: This solution should be perfectly fine in most situations, but what if the browser is driven by means of a remote webdriver server and/or the download link only works when various session cookie, IP address or network access requirements are met? It would be useful with a solution that uses the actual browser to check if the link works. (If the webdriver protocol supports it.)

Comment: @OttoG you could do the same with [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) in headless mode