# Validating download file in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, ecmascript-6, nightwatch.js

I am Trying to write a test using nightwatch js to validate the file is downloaded after click on button/link in the web page. No need to check data inside file, i would only require to check if the file is downloaded or not.
Also before I download I have to delete the existing files from download folder so that copy of same file doesn't occur. How this can be achieved in Nightwatch js? Please help me.

Comment: try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370238/testing-download-links-with-nightwatch-js

Comment: i haven't tried it with content length as of now,
i am new to nightwatch js , if i had to click on button in web page and check the file is downloaded or not what value i would need to pass in "path": value (it is a button tag in the DOM , if it was a anchor tag then i would passed href attribute value)